# Help installing and configuring an Cisco ASA 5505 firewall?

Tags: firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

I’m having some difficulties installing the Cisco ASA 5505 firewall at my company. We had an old firewall (Zyxel) which caused a lot of problems so I was recommended the ASA 5505 firewall from Cisco.

The old setup on the Zyxel was two Ethernet cables: A WLAN cable and a LAN cable. On the back of the Zyxel firewall it was fairly easy because there is only two sockets stating: WLAN and LAN so plug them in and there is connection to the Internet.

But when I’m trying to follow the same kind of pattern on my Cisco I get no connection. I plug the WLAN cable into the port 0 (the outside port) and a cable which runs up to our switch into port 1 (as it state in the manual) but I get no connection what so ever.

Right now, the configuration looks like this:

Internet --> Model --> ASA --> Switch --> PC’s and Servers

Am I missing something? I should say, it is my first time installing a hardware firewall so I might misunderstand something.

Thanks very much for your help.

Sincere
Mestika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you're missing something. The ASA needs to be configured, not just plugged in.

[Google](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=cisco+asa+5505+configuration+guide&cp=29&qe=Y2lzY28gYXNhIDU1MDUgY29uZmlndXJhdGlvbiA&qesig=EAKD6rejppOh2QkTJZuzAQ&pkc=AFgZ2tl0xnTMwbE_-T88uT9eHdXPbdQg0sWYCznf4wBZl-NTGaqod_CW2BN34Vw7E-aJmC_pSyiUF3Vrd2odrN9SpeUZdehIMg&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=cisco+asa+5505+configuration+&pbx=1&fp=d154f5edca559ee3)

Comment: Could you might elaborate because I have a hard time seeing how to configure it. I try to do as the manual says and then type in "https://192.168.1.1/admin/" as it says but it is like it can't access it.

Comment: My guess is that your internal network is not on the 192.168.1.0 subnet. You should be able to connect a workstation/laptop directly to the internal interface on the ASA, configure the workstation/laptop with a 192.168.1.x/24 ip address/mask and connect that way.

Comment: I would recommend using the serial console for the initial configuration. That way you can get the OS upgraded before putting it on the network.

Comment: No need to be a dick with the answer :-)

Comment: @James Cape: What? How is that?

Comment: joeqwerty: The questioner obviously had no idea what they were getting into with an ASA, but your answer is very much just "RTFM".

Comment: And there's something wrong with telling someone to RTFM, especially if they're new to the subject? So we should all forsake reading the documentation in favor of posting our questions on some forum and hoping to get what we need? You know what I do before I post a question? I RTFM. In addition, if you're that strongly opposed to directing someone to the documentation (opposed enough to downvote my answer for doing just that) then why haven't you posted the step-by-step instructions for the OP? Your calling me a dick seems a little bit like the pot calling the kettle black.

Comment: @James Cape: Will you be reviewing all the questions at SF then and downvoting those that instruct the questioner to RTFM? Just curious.

Comment: @joeqwerty: Yes, there is something wrong with *only* (or "just") telling someone to RTFM. It's always rude, and rarely all that helpful even if the recipient ignores the rudeness.

Comment: @James Cape: To be fair, I didn't just tell him to RTFM. I did tell him that the firewall needed to be configured and not jut merely plugged in and I included a link to a Google search related to configuring the ASA. That's a little more than just telling him to RTFM. At any rate I think your downvote was uncalled for. Alas, To each his own... I'm moving on.